# Function that change all instanses acording to one instanse that change

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a class called 'Session' which has one value in it, called 'time'.
I want to create a function that changes one instance 'time' and the delta will divide between the others, no matter how much instances I create.

example: sess1.time = 45, sess2.time = 60, sess3.time = 50
If I add 5 to sess1.time, each of the other two will decrease by 2.

here is my code so far:

```js
class Workshop {
    constructor(name, desc) {
      this.name = name;
      this.desc = desc;
    }

    getWork() {
      console.log(this.name + " " + this.desc);
    }
}

class Session extends Workshop {
    constructor(name, desc, time){
        super(name, desc);
        this.time = time;
    }
    getSession() {
        console.log(this.name + " " + this.desc + " " + this.time);
    }
    changeTime(newTime) {
        let delta = this.time - newTime;
        this.time = newTime;

    }
}

let sessionList = [
    sess1 = new Session('hummus', 'yamyam', 45),
    sess2 = new Session('Kabab', 'mmmmmm', 70)
]

sessionList.forEach((session) => {
    console.log(session.time);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep an array of Session instances:

```
 const sessions = []; // this is leaking though

 class Session extends Workshop {
   constructor(name, desc, time){
      super(name, desc);
      this.time = time;
      sessions.push(this); // collect all created sessions
   }

   getSession() {
      console.log(this.name + " " + this.desc + " " + this.time);
   }

   changeTime(newTime) {
      let delta = this.time - newTime;
      // apply the delta to all other sessions
      for(const other of sessions) {
       if(other === this) continue;
       other.time -= delta / (sessions.length - 1);
      }
      this.time = newTime;
   }
}
```

it might be benefitial to explecitly manage a group of `sessions` instead of having a leaking global.

Comment: Good note that explicitly managing these would be a lot better than quietly, mysteriously managing them. Globals like this could get cluttered up if this is involved in some kind of looping code or web-style request/response loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create session counter and pass it to function and with conditional if statment do your work according to counter value

```
 class Workshop {
    constructor(name, desc) {
      this.name = name;
      this.desc = desc;
    }
    getWork() {
      console.log(this.name + " " + this.desc);
    }
}
class Session extends Workshop {
    constructor(name, desc, time){
        super(name, desc);
        this.time = time;
    }
    getSession() {
        console.log(this.name + " " + this.desc + " " + this.time);
    }
    changeTime(newTime,i) {
        if(i==0){
            let delta = this.time + newTime;
            this.time = delta;
        }
        else {
            let delta = this.time -2;
            this.time = delta;
        }
        return this.time
    }
}
let sessionList = [
    sess1 = new Session('hummus', 'yamyam', 45),
    sess2 = new Session('Kabab', 'mmmmmm', 70)
 ]
var i=0;
sessionList.forEach((session) => {
    session.changeTime(5,i);
    i++;
    console.log(session.time);
});
```